Cloning nested datasets
I have two nested TClientDataSets linked with the DataSetField property.
I need to lookup other records in the child dataset OnBeforePost so I clone the child for that:
if not ASourceDataSet.Active then ASourceDataSet.Open;
ACopyDataSet.CloneCursor(ASourceDataSet,true,false)

Issues: In the BeforePost, the clone is Active, the Evaluate/Modify inspector says RecordCount=0 (not true), and stepping in the RecordCount function gives me a C0000005 ACCESS VIOLATION on the FDSCursor.GetRecordCount.
function TCustomClientDataSet.GetRecordCount: Integer;
var
  Status: DBResult;
begin
  CheckActive;
  if (FParentDataSet <> nil) and (FParentDataSet.State <> dsInsert) then     // dsEdit at this moment
    FParentDataSet.UpdateCursorPos;              // Cannot step into this
  Status := FDSCursor.GetRecordCount(Result);    // FDSCursor <> nil
  if Status <> DBERR_DETAILSNOTFETCHED then
    Check(Status);
end;

Is maybe only cloning the child not allowed?

Child state is dsBrowse at this moment
I checked some other properties like FieldCount (7, correct).
All three datasets exist design time
I tried cloning the parent and working from there, but that went wrong also.
64 bit Delphi 12 app


After doing a CloneCursor you still need to make it active / open it before using it. Some operations do open the underlying dataset if it isn't already so it's not always required to have an explicit open but it doesn't hurt.

@Brain That's not it. I forgot too mention that lookup dataset state is dsBrowse. Question updated
